# How should I handle the maturation of my savings bonds?

Tags: united-states, savings-bonds, maturity

I recently found out from my father that I own 5 U.S. savings bonds, valued at roughly 50 dollars when deposited, some of which are about to start maturing (one in 2017 will be worth around 90 dollars, and another one every five years with about a 10% increase in returns).

Having completely forgotten about these, and with no idea what to actually do with them, how should I handle the maturation of my savings bonds?  I am completely unfamiliar with how to handle the maturation of deposits like this.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeredeem.htm

Most banks will redeem paper bonds; the link above has the US Treasury's mailing address if needed.